# To return output in a given format when takes input as a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

In this problem I got the output but I can't figure out how to change few things. I got the total salary but I can't understand how to change the keys and get this format.

I want output in this format

```
{
    "433": {
        employee_name: 'Rishi',
        total_salary: 5200
  },
    "434": {
        employee_name: 'pathak',
        total_salary: 5600 
  },
    "435": {
        employee_name: 'partap',
        total_salary: 5700
      }
  }
```

```
    function takeInput(output){
            let total = [];
            let totalSalary = [];
            for(let i=0; i< output.length; i++){
                if(typeof(output[i].employee_data.salary[0]) == "object"){
                    total[i] = output[i].employee_data.salary[0];  
                    totalSalary[i] = addSalary(total[i]);
                    output[i].employee_data.salary[0]  = addSalary(total[i]);
                    console.log(output[i]);  
                }
            }
        }
        
        function addSalary(income){
            let total = 0;
            let values = Object.values(income)
            for(let i=0; i< values.length; i++){
              total = total + values[i];
            }
            return total;
        }
        
        
        
        let output = [
            {
              employee_data: {
                  employee_name: 'Rishi',
                  id: "433",
                  salary: [{'march': 1200, 'april': 2000, 'may': 2000}]
              }
            },
            {
                employee_data: {
                  employee_name: 'pathak',
                  id: "434",
                    salary: [{'march': 1100, 'april': 2200, 'may': 2300}]
                }
            },
            {
                employee_data: {
                  employee_name: 'partap',
                  id: "435",
                    salary: [{'march': 1200, 'april': 2200, 'may': 2300}]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: So, the input to your `takeInput` function is named `output`? That's not confusing at all... :/

Answer (score 2):

```
    let output = [
    {
      employee_data: {
          employee_name: 'Rishi',
          id: "433",
          salary: [{'march': 1200, 'april': 2000, 'may': 2000}]
      }
    },
    {
        employee_data: {
          employee_name: 'pathak',
          id: "434",
            salary: [{'march': 1100, 'april': 2200, 'may': 2300}]
        }
    },
    {
        employee_data: {
          employee_name: 'partap',
          id: "435",
            salary: [{'march': 1200, 'april': 2200, 'may': 2300}]
        }
    }
]

function addSalary(income){
    let total = 0;
    let values = Object.values(income)
    for(let i=0; i< values.length; i++){
      total = total + values[i];
    }
    return total;
}

const modifyOutput = (output) => {
    const newOutput = {}
    output.forEach(o => {
        newOutput[o.employee_data.id] = {
            employee_name: o.employee_data.employee_name,
            salary: addSalary(o.employee_data.salary[0])
        }
    })
    console.log(newOutput);
}

modifyOutput(output);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of ***reduce()*** methods to get the expected output.

```js
const output = [{
    employee_data: {
      employee_name: 'Rishi',
      id: "433",
      salary: [{
        'march': 1200,
        'april': 2000,
        'may': 2000
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    employee_data: {
      employee_name: 'pathak',
      id: "434",
      salary: [{
        'march': 1100,
        'april': 2200,
        'may': 2300
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    employee_data: {
      employee_name: 'partap',
      id: "435",
      salary: [{
        'march': 1200,
        'april': 2200,
        'may': 2300
      }]
    }
  }
];

const result = output.reduce((obj, user_prop) => {
  obj[user_prop.employee_data.id] = {
    "employee_name": user_prop.employee_data.employee_name,
    "total_salary": user_prop.employee_data.salary.reduce((total, current) => {
      return total + Object.values(current).reduce((num1, num2) => num1 + num2, 0);
    }, 0),
  };
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let output = [{employee_data: {employee_name: 'Rishi',id: "433",salary: [{'march': 1200,'april': 2000,'may': 2000}]}},{employee_data: {employee_name: 'pathak',id: "434",salary: [{'march': 1100,'april': 2200,'may': 2300}]}},{employee_data: {employee_name: 'partap',id: "435",salary: [{'march': 1200,'april': 2200,'may': 2300}]}}];

// reduce the output to a single object
let newOutput = output.reduce((obj, entry) => {
  
  // destructure the object into three variables
  let { employee_name, id, salary } = entry.employee_data;
  
  // this will cause issues if your `id`s are not unique
  // creates a new entry for each id
  obj[id] = { employee_name, salary };
  
  // keep the object to continue editing
  return obj;
  
}, {} /* <-- this is the object we are starting with (empty) */ );

console.log(newOutput);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%} /* format the preview */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of reduce() methods to derive the totals.

```
 // iterate through the data array
let output = data.reduce((b, a) => ({ ...b, 
 // return the accumulator b, adding in
 // a new object with the employee id as the key
  ...{ [a.employee_data.id]: {
        employee_name: a.employee_data.employee_name,
        // the total salary is summed through another reduce, this time, taking the Object.values() of salary and adding them together
        total_salary: Object.values(a.employee_data.salary[0]).reduce((d, c) => d + c, 0)
      }
    }
  }), {})
```

```js
let data = 
    {
      employee_data: {
          employee_name: 'Rishi',
          id: "433",
          salary: [{'march': 1200, 'april': 2000, 'may': 2000}]
      }
    },
    {
        employee_data: {
          employee_name: 'pathak',
          id: "434",
            salary: [{'march': 1100, 'april': 2200, 'may': 2300}]
        }
    },
    {
        employee_data: {
          employee_name: 'partap',
          id: "435",
            salary: [{'march': 1200, 'april': 2200, 'may': 2300}]
        }
    }
]

// iterate through the data array
let output = data.reduce((b, a) => (
 // return the accumulator b, adding in...
  { ...b, ...{
  // a new object with the employee id as the key
      [a.employee_data.id]: {
        employee_name: a.employee_data.employee_name,
        // the total salary is summed through another reduce, this time, taking the Object.values() of salary and adding them together
        total_salary: Object.values(a.employee_data.salary[0]).reduce((d, c) => d + c, 0)
      }
    }
  }), {})
  
console.log(output)
```